# Why doesn't this regex code return anything?

Tags: python, regex

Why doesn't this regex code return anything?

```
#Searches for a pattern in string
pattern = r'[a-zA-Z ]*' 
string = '111-456-7890 This is my number... Gimme a ring.'
match = re.search(pattern, string)
match
```

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: By "return anything", do you mean "print it to the terminal"?. `match` on its own doesn't do anything, but `print(match)` might show you something

Comment: All you want to know [has already been explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27876846/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

The star is a false friend, try this:

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

Try your statements with: https://regexr.com/

If you use re.search, deaktivate global flag that gives you only the first word.

Answer (score 0):

You `match` is "only" an object of type `re.Match`, you have to use it in the `if` statement in the form

```
if match:
    # Some code, if pattern was found
```

or use some of its methods to obtain some details, e. g.

```
match.start()
```

returns the starting position (index) of the pattern in your string, i.e. `12` for your (little modified) `pattern` `r'[a-zA-Z ]+'` and `string`.

Example of the full code:

```
import re

pattern = r'[a-zA-Z ]+'
string = '111-456-7890 This is my number... Gimme a ring.'
match = re.search(pattern, string)

if match:
    print("Start position:", match.start())
    print("Matching part:" , match.group())
else:
    print("No match.")
```

The output:

> ```
> Start position: 12
> Matching part:  This is my number
> ```

Comment: Yes, but for example in Juypter the code above prints something if match is not nothing: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(13, 17), match='This'>