# Greedy operator *in regex

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
string  = "piiigi"
m = re.search(r'i*',string)
print m.group()
```

This gives me an empty string, shouldn't it be 'iii', could you please tell me how * works, similarly i? gives an empty string

I do get output for i+

Also let's say

```
s = "    this is some sentence"
m = re.search(r'\w*', s)
```

m.group() is giving me  an empty string

Since I'm using search shouldn't I be getting "this"?

Comment: Regexes find the leftmost match.

Comment: Yes,leftmost is i then i* should match iii right?

Comment: @sans0909 `*` means zero or more. The very start of the string matches that criteria (zero to be precise).

Comment: Use the `+` quantifier for one or more.

Comment: [Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27876846/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

if you will try to change search to findall and print m you can see all the matches the regex `'i*'` will find:

```
import re
string  = "piiigi"
m = re.findall(r'i*',string)
print(m)
```

and the output is:

```
['', 'iii', '', 'i', '']
```

as the comments say, search will return the FIRST match (leftmost), and as `*` can be zero sized match, you get an empty match result.

to elaborate: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding
>   MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches
>   the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length
>   match at some point in the string.