# * and + behaving differently in regex python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am using python re module. I am not able to get why following two are behaving differently. I am expecting that the one with * will also give same result.

```
re.search(r'([0-9]+)',':329392.899')
```

Output: re.Match object; span=(1, 7), match='329392'

```
re.search('([0-9]*)',':329392.899')
```

Output: re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''

Comment: The two code quotes do not only differ in `*/+`. Did you note the difference in the `r` ?

Comment: Both with and without r give same result

Comment: @Yunnosch The `r` makes no difference, there are no escape sequences in the regexp.

Comment: **This [has already been dealt thorouhly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27876846/3832970).** It is expected, and there is no issue. You receive what you ask for: an empty match at the start of the string.

Comment: But, it's all about the current position. If optional (i.e. the `*`), any position will match. At position 0 in the string it matched. However, if `print (re.search(r'([0-9]*)','329392.899'))` was used, it would match the numbers even though optional. It's all about options. When optional and nothing matches the current position is advanced by 1 and it matches again until it optionally comes to a set of digits.

Comment: The has been quite a few questions related to this same issue and I [recorded a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYfeX_zsDzI&list=PL0l350Bvl3lKYZXelzEQCW0s7DUxzQzUq) where I explained this problem in more details.

Answer (score 2):

`re.search` will first attempt to find a match starting at the beginning of the string, and only advance the starting position when a match cannot be found. The `[0-9]*` pattern does match the at the beginning of the string, it just matches zero characters (`*` matches zero or more).

Answer (score 1):

`*` matches zero or more of the pattern. There are zero digits at the very beginning of the input string, before the `:`, it's matching that.

`+` matches one or more of the pattern, so it doesn't find a match until it gets to the `3`, then it matches all the digits.

Answer (score 1):

`*` means match zero or more time, so when you use `([0-9]*)` it will match ( capture ) empty string also which is why you get `Output: re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''`

Whereas on the other hand `+` means one or more so it won't capture the empty string

Have a look at demo and see the highlighted matches and `matched values`, also you're missing `r` in second snippet

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/VhKPeK/1/)